# How can update an <input/> field in tapestry by AJAX request

Tags: ajax, tapestry

I have a project developed with tapestry 5. 
I need to update a input field (which is inside a form) using an AJAX request.

Page.tml is something like this:

```
<form>
    <t:zone t:id="myZone">
        <input type="text" t:type="TextField" t:value="product.code"/>
    </t:zone>
    <t:actionlink t:id="generateCode" zone="myZone">Generate</t:actionlink>
</form>
```

And Page.java

```
Object onActionFromGenerateCode() {
    return myZone.body();
}
```

When click in "Generate" link, tapestry throws an exception. Don't let me update a zone inside a form:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException
The component must be enclosed by a Form component.
```

How can I update this input field?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Changing pieces of a form via ajax gets tricky as a [FormSupport](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/services/FormSupport.html) instance must be available on the [Environment](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/services/Environment.html) in the serverside event.

It might be easier to either:

1. Put the entire form in a zone and refresh the whole form
2. Execute some javascript from the serverside event

Here's how option 2 could work:

TML

```
<form>
    <input id="productCode" type="text" t:type="TextField" t:value="product.code" />
    <!-- note that async is a recent addition to eventlink in tapestry 5.4 -->
    <!-- Use a dummy zone for previous versions -->
    <t:eventlink event="generateCode" async="true">Generate</t:eventlink>
</form>
```

Java

```
@Inject JavaScriptSupport jss

void onGenerateCode() {
    String productCode = generateProductCode();
    jss.addScript("$('#productCode').val('%s');", productCode); // assuming jquery
}
```

Note, it is possible to dynamically change a form via ajax, it's just tricky as I said. Examples include [AjaxFormLoop](http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/examples/ajax/formloop1) and the [FormInjector](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.4/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/FormInjector.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I dont have this project any more. I cant test it :(

Comment: Lance, I know it's old topic, but could you please elaborate on why it's tricky regarding this FormSupport? Or maybe you can point to some sources. I've tried to examine the examples you've provided, but I still don't understand that.